# Creating a coin flip class

Tags: java

I have recently begun programming at university and I am a little stumped with one of my tutorial problems.

I basically need to create a method within a class which uses the Random.nextInt()
method to flip a coin, assigning and saving the value once the process has been run.

MY current attempts include this:

```
public void Flip() {

int flipResult;

flipResult = mRandNumGen.nextInt(1);

if(flipResult == 0)
{
mFace = 'H';
}
else
{
mFace = 'T'
}

}
```

mFace and mRandNumGen are variables which have been declared already outside the specific method. What exactly is going wrong here? I can't for the life of me get this to work :/

Comment: So exactly what happens when you run your code? Do you get an error?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon in the else block, and make sure you're using `char` data type.

Comment: the error say at cointest.Coin.Flip(Coin.java:46) and at cointest.CoinTest.main(CoinTest.java:26). Java returned:1 BUILD FAILED

Comment: Can you please paste the full message, or at least mark which lines are 26 and 46

Answer (score 3):

Simple way to do this:

```
if (mRandNumGen.nextBoolean()) {
    mFace = 'H';
} else {
    mFace = 'T';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first argument in `Random.nextInt` is an exclusive upper bound, not inclusive.
So with n=1 it will always return 0. for n=2 it will return either 0 or 1 which is what you're looking for.